# React Js Node Js Axios Response Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, error-handling, multer

I am having trouble successfully returning response messages to be viewed. I was able to do so before, but after making some changes to my middleware and route.post to see if catch files that were already uploaded, I am no longer able to catch errors. I use node js on the backend and react js on the frontend.

React JS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers.css';
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import moment from 'react-moment';

const NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers = () => {
    const [flyerName, setFullName] = useState(null);
    const [flyerEventDate, setFlyerEventDate] = useState(null);
    const [flyerDescription, setFlyerDescription] = useState(null);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
    const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const Navigate = useNavigate();

    const submitForm = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const url = 'http://localhost:3001/Flyer/Flyer_Upload';
        
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('flyerName', flyerName);
        data.append('flyerEventDate', flyerEventDate);
        data.append('flyerDescription', flyerDescription);
        for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++){
            data.append('files', selectedFile[x]);
        }
        
        Axios.post(url, data)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.message != null){
                setStatusMessage(response.data.message);
            }
            else {
                Navigate('/NewsAndFlyers');
            }
        });
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='newsAndFlyersUploadFlyersBody'>
                <h1>Upload A Flyers</h1>
                <div className='flyerInfoFormBody'>
                <p className='flyerName'>*Event Name: <input name='flyerName' placeholder='Event Name' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)} /></p>
                <p className='flyerEventDate'>*Event Date: <input name='flyerEventDate' type='date' placeholder='Event Date' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFlyerEventDate(e.target.value)} /></p>
                <p className='flyerDescription'>*Flyer Description: <textarea name='flyerDescription' placeholder='Flyer Description' required autoComplete="off" onChange={(e) => setFlyerDescription(e.target.value)} /> </p>
                <p>*Upload the flyer.</p>
                <input className='uploadFiles' type='file' name='file' required onChange={(e) => setSelectedFile(e.target.files)} /></div>
                {isLoading && <button className='uploadButton' disabled>Loading</button>}
                {!isLoading && <button className='uploadButton' onClick={submitForm}>Upload Flyer</button>}
                <h2>{statusMessage}</h2>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}

export default NewsAndFlyerUploadFlyers;
```

Node JS Middleware:

```
const flyerDestination = './routes/Flyers'
const flyerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb){ 
    return cb(null, flyerDestination)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(flyerDestination,file.originalname))) {
      return cb(new Error("Flyer already exists"));
    } else {
      return cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  }
});
const flyerUpload = multer({ storage: flyerStorage }).array('files');
```

Node JS Route.post

```
router.post('/Flyer_Upload', (req, res) => {
  flyerUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    const flyerName = req.body.flyerName;
    const flyerEventDate = req.body.flyerEventDate;
    const flyerDescription = req.body.flyerDescription;
    const flyerID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    const flyerDirectory = 'http://localhost:3001/Flyers/';
    var uploadFlyer = true;
    var multerMessage = null;
    
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      uploadFlyer = false;
      multerMessage = 'An Error Occurred During Upload!';
    } else if (res.status(409)) {
      uploadFlyer = false;
      multerMessage = 'Flyer already exists';
    } else if (res.status(500)){
      uploadFlyer = false;
      multerMessage = 'A Bad Request Was Recieved!';
    } else if (err){
      uploadFlyer = false;
      multerMessage = 'An Unknown Error Occurred!';
    }

    if (multerMessage == null){
      for (const file of req.files) {
        directory = path.dirname(file.path);
        const flyerUploadedPath = flyerDirectory + file.filename
        
        //Delete Once Successful
        console.log('flyerName: ' + flyerName);
        console.log('flyerEventDate: ' + flyerEventDate);
        console.log('flyerDescription: ' + flyerDescription);
        console.log('flyerID: ' + flyerID);      
        console.log('File path: ' + flyerUploadedPath);     

        db.query('INSERT INTO flyerinfo (flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerURL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerUploadedPath], (err, res) => {
            if (err){
              return res.json({message: 'An Error Occurred!' });
            }
          });
        return res.status(200).send(req.files);
      }
    } else {
      console.log (multerMessage)
      return res.json({message: multerMessage });
    }
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: you can do like this :  `axios.post(url).then(...){something}.catch(err){console.log(err), err.response, err.status,  etc...}` to find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Axios.get(url, data)
  .then(() => {
   //...
   })
  .catch((error) {
    console.log(error.request); //Or error.message
});
```

to catch errors.
You can also go through with this [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)